# Need help sending location data to a server in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, server, mapkit

I don't have a server set up yet, but my app requires the location of other people on the app to work.  I need help taking each location and putting it with all the others in an array to be used, and later sent back to the phone. Thanks in advance.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()//
    }
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking. 
You want to create fake data that your application could use as mocked server response ?

Comment: no i want to program everything except the specific server that the data will go to

Comment: Is the server API specified ?

Comment: id like to use cloud kit but I'm completely new to documenting user data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your intent completely, but here are some ad hoc comments:

`Dictionary` might be more practical data storage for this purpose. Individual users can be added/removed, directly accessed when the user position changes and needs to be updated and if you want, you can access the data in the same fashion as `Array`.

Consider using [`requestLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestLocation) instead of `didUpdateLocations` if you need just one reading.

I think CloudKit might have all you need to implement the server part.

In order to find the region of the map that encompasses all locations, you need to take all coordinates and find top left and bottom right coordinate and use that in the `MKCoordinateRegion`

Comment: how could i send that data to cloud kit

Comment: It is not very difficult, if you have a simple table, but you will need to setup the infrastructure (create database, table...). You can start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html